# java.net.SocketException:Unexpected end of file from the server [but this message comes only with one particular user login

Tags: java, spring

We have a client server application which runs using spring remoting framework and we are using jetty server and Java 1.7. We deliver both client and server to the customers.

At one of customer's office, for one of the user login, he is getting this Exception which is mentioned in the title of the postjava.net.SocketException:Unexpected end of file from the server. He is actually doing the search for something which makes a server call and finally he ends up getting this error in the error log.

The weird thing is, nobody else in the Customer's office gets this error. It is very weird.

And also i googled about this exception but did not get appropriate answer.

Please provide your suggestions.

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://192.168.13.211:6094/SearchFieldServer]; nested exception is ava.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:211)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.search(Unknown Source)
    at se.transware.awt.SearchFieldModel.setObjectIdAndReload(SearchFieldModel.java:329)
    at se.transware.awt.SearchFieldModel.setObjectIdAndReload(SearchFieldModel.java:293)
    at se.transware.awt.SearchFieldModel.setObjectID(SearchFieldModel.java:282)
    at se.transware.awt.SearchField.setOid(SearchField.java:740)
    at se.transware.tt.client.register.CustomerClientRegGUI.load(CustomerClientRegGUI.java:3885)
    at se.transware.tt.client.register.CustomerClientRegLogic.pseudoConstructor(CustomerClientRegLogic.java:786)
    at se.transware.tt.client.main.ModuleController.flipApp(ModuleController.java:222)
    at se.transware.tt.client.main.SystemResources.flipApp(SystemResources.java:260)
    at se.transware.tt.client.register.RegObjectsTableLogicClientAdapter.editRegObject(RegObjectsTableLogicClientAdapter.java:511)
    at se.transware.tt.client.register.RegObjectsTable2$18.mouseClicked(RegObjectsTable2.java:1150)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.validateResponse(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:141)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Does he get this error on another computer in the same office?

Comment: Yes..He gets this error on another computer with his login. But nobody else is getting this error. The problem is with that particular user only.

Comment: What happens if you do exactly the same search on a different user account?

Comment: It works fine for different user account.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links which you probably already found :

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7076649
http://www.coderanch.com/t/207583/sockets/java/java-net-SocketException-Unexpected-file
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Caused-by-java-net-SocketException-Unexpected-end-of-file-from-server-td4715340.html

Additionally, if you can share some code snippet or stack trace we can share more realistic comments on this issue. Maybe it is caused by some security options of the client facing this issue.

Are all customers configuration the same?

Comment: All the customer's configuration's are same. I dont think there are any security problems of the client. because some other user could login to the client with his own login credentials and could do anything perfectly with out any problem. I will post the stack trace soon..

Comment: I think this is stack trace from client side. It shows that socket connection is closed by the server while client side is listening the socket. Do you have any logs from server side?

Comment: yes. this is the stack trace from client side. no error is logged in server side. But one surprise thing is, it does not work only for one particular user. it works fine for all others users.